# How to format correctly this date: '2015-09-25 13:00:00+00:00'

Tags: python-3.x, date-formatting

I'm trying to plot a dataset from a cryptocurrency exchange called Bitmex.
The code from the tutorial I'm following in order to plot a candlestick:

```
`# Convert 'Timestamp' to 'float'.
#   candlestick_ohlc needs time to be in float days format - see date2num().
loaded_data['date'] = [mdates.date2num(d) for d in loaded_data['date']]`
```

But my dates are in a str format ex. '2015-09-25 13:00:00+00:00'

Now I'm trying alternatives to get to the same result:
    `data['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+:%Z') for d in data['timestamp']]`

but I'm getting the following error:
    `ValueError: time data '2015-09-25 13:00:00+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+:%Z'`

Comment: That's a very unusual datetime string, where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 1):

Use dateutil.parser:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

get_date_obj = parse("2015-09-25 13:00:00+00:00")
print(get_date_obj)
```

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is another way at the moment. datetime.strptime doesn't support the '+00:00' for utc offset yet.